# Multi-parameter stationary phase asymptotic expansion

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for an asymptotic expansion of the oscillatory integral of the form
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\exp(i(\lambda_1\phi_1(x)+\dots+\lambda_k\phi_k(x))dx,$$
as $\lambda_i\to \infty$ independently, where $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\phi_i$ are smooth.

When all $\lambda_i$ are equal an asymptotic expansion can be given by usual stationary phase analysis. I am unable to find any literature which discusses about different $\lambda_i$.

Thanks for any reference.

Answer (score 1):

The case of two parameters was worked out by D. Sather in [Stationary phase for two parameters with an application to Bessel functions.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-12/issue-4/Asymptotics-III-Stationary-phase-for-two-parameters-with-an-application/pjm/1103036142.full)